# I am creating a collection by mongoose in node, but it is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

```
schema = new mongoose.Schema
    name: String
    html: String
    alias: String
    title: String
    description: String
    keywords: String

schema.index alias: 1

Models.Page = mongoose.model 'Page', schema
```

And after I am creating a document in collection Page.

```
a = new Models.Page name: 'a', alias: 'a', title: 'a'
do a.save
```

But `a` doesn’t get any field of my object and it is can not be saved.
What to do?

Mongoose@4.2
Mongodb@3.2

Comment: Can you define _"can not be saved"_? Are you getting errors?

Comment: @robertklep no errors. Model just don't get fields. variable a don't have field name, alias and title. No errors. Nothing.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem? Your code looks okay.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry. I have redefined my model after.

Comment: What? Could you describe more precisely how you solved this issue?